# odoo js error Cannot read property 'include' of undefined while include function to base calendar

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

i want modification the base_calendar.js with new custom function like below

```
CalendarNotification = require('base_calendar.base_calendar');

console.log("Masuk sini bawah");

CalendarNotification.include({
    'click .link2showed': function() {
        console.log("ndak yo mlebu kene to");
        var action = {
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: 'crm.lead',
            view_mode: 'form',
            view_type: 'form',
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            res_id: 16644
        };
        this.do_action(action);
    },
});
```

and this a base_calendar.js odoo addons

```
var Notification = require('web.notification').Notification;

var CalendarNotification = Notification.extend({
    template: "CalendarNotification",

    init: function(parent, title, text, eid) {
        this._super(parent, title, text, true);
        this.eid = eid;

        this.events = _.extend(this.events || {}, {
            'click .link2event': function() {
                var self = this;

                this.rpc("/web/action/load", {
                    action_id: "calendar.action_calendar_event_notify",
                }).then(function(r) {
                    r.res_id = self.eid;
                    return self.do_action(r);
                });
            },

            'click .link2recall': function() {
                this.destroy(true);
            },
            'click .link2showed2': function() {
                this.destroy(true);
                this.rpc("/calendar/notify_ack");

            },
        });
    },
});
```

How do I fix that and what causes it? I've been several times custom function JS like that and it worked well.

Thank in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Use '**extend**' insted of '**include**'

Comment: @KevalMehta thank for answer, ya extend will fix the error and it need custom in xml, i found solution extend qweb base_calendar and change class button name.

Comment: @EndyRahman can you be more specific  please ! i've got the same problem 'Cannot read property 'do_action' of undefined'